# How to prevent useState from rerendering the component again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

[image: RadioButton changing their positions]

```js
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import React from 'react';

export default function Question(props) {
  const answers = [...props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer];

  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = React.useState();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectedAnswer(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  // Randomize answer of the Question
  function createRandom(arr) {
    let myArr = [...arr];
    let randomizedArr = [];

    while (myArr.length > 0) {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArr.length);
      randomizedArr.push(myArr[randomIndex]);
      myArr.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    }
    return randomizedArr;
  }
  const randomizedArr = createRandom(answers);

  // RadioButton for the answers
  const RadioButton = ({ label, value, onChange }) => {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="answers"
          value={value}
          checked={selectedAnswer === value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        {label}
      </label>
    );
  };

  const answersElements = randomizedArr.map((answer) => {
    return (
      <RadioButton
        key={nanoid()}
        label={answer}
        value={answer}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="question-row">
      <div className="single-question">{props.question}</div>
      <div className="answers">{answersElements}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: RadioButton changing their positions]

When I select a radiobutton `answer` , React rerender the `RaidoButton` component and call my `Randomize` function which randomize the answers.
I do not know how to prevent `Randomize` function from being called after the first time.
in the two pictures when I select an answer for the first question , the answers get randomized again , I want to prevent this behavior

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BARNOWL what is part of the question that you did not understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You **need** the component to rerender when the state changes (if for no other reason than to update which radio button is checked).

The problem is that you need the randomisation function to run only on the initial load.

---

Create a state for the randomized array:

```
const [randomizedArr, setRandomizedArr] = useState([]);
```

Then populate it in an effect hook with an empty dependency array (so it only runs on the initial load of the component).

```
useEffect(() => {
    const randomizedArr = createRandom(answers);
    setRandomizedArr(randomizedArr);
}, []);
```

Comment: missing answers as a dependency array , if I provide it I will end at the same loop

Comment: Put `const answers = [...props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer];` inside the effect too then.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [randomizedArr, setRandomizedArr] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const answers = [...props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer];
    const randomizedArr = createRandom(answers);
    setRandomizedArr(randomizedArr);
  }, [props.incorrect_answers, props.correct_answer]);
```